# PostgreSQL if temporary table is dropped query is empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, temporary-objects

I'm working on a rather simple homework assignment where I have to retrieve some data that complies with some criteria and then run another query on the data that was selected in the previous query.

I create a temporary table and populate it with the results of the first query and then run a second query on the table. Then I drop the table.

Here's the problem: If I drop the table, the second query is empty as result is discarded. I don't understand this. I don't use temporary table for select, only for data validation. And yet if the table is dropped at the end of the query, the query returns empty. If I don't drop the table it works fine. But if I run the query again it says table exists. What am I doing wrong here. Here's the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gno
INTO TEMPORARY TABLE TMP
FROM edge
WHERE weight>100;

SELECT  gname, gsum(graph.gno)
FROM TMP, graph
WHERE graph.gno = TMP.gno AND gsum(graph.gno)>=ALL
(SELECT gsum(graph.gno)
FROM graph);
```

Comment: Please show the application code that's invoking this SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary tables are created in a special temporary schema, unique to each session. They are only visible in the same session and only until the end of the session (unless dropped earlier).

That temporary schema *implicitly* is the first schema in the [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) (after the system schema `pg_catalog`), so it effectively hides other tables of the same name. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)

> Existing permanent tables with the same name are not visible to the
>   current session while the temporary table exists, unless they are
>   referenced with schema-qualified names.

Once you drop the temp table, the next table with the same name in the `search_path` becomes visible again. And that table does not have any matching values in its existing `gno` column. So the result is empty.

That must be the case because, if no such table existed, you wouldn't get an *empty* result but an error message for the next attempt.

Also, your second query should rather be:

```
SELECT  gname, gsum(graph.gno)
FROM    tmp
JOIN    graph USING (gno)
WHERE   gsum(graph.gno) = (
   SELECT max(gsum(graph.gno))
   FROM   graph
   );
```

With explicit `JOIN` syntax and simplified `WHERE` condition.
Assuming `gsum()` is a plain function, *not* an aggregate function.